# Interpretation of lasso recovery results

Tags: correlation, lasso, causality, sparse

When people say that lasso regression can under certain assumptions recover "the support", i.e. non-zero regression weights, what does this mean?

This cannot mean *causal* recovery, because Pearl has taught us you cannot infer causality from correlation (and lasso is just glorified correlation). So are these non-zeros in some way the minimum set of variables that cannot be explained by others? Because people tend to speak in terms of removing "spurious" and recovering "non-spurious" correlation, but really how can correlation be spurious, it's just the association between two random variables, there's no room for causal language here.

I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what people mean by support recovery is very simple. If the observed data is generated using a model of the form $$y=Xw^*+\epsilon$$
$y\in\mathbb{R}^n, X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p},\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is noise (assumed to be subGaussian), where $w^*\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is known to be sparse, under what conditions will the solution of the lasso problem

$$\hat{w}=\arg\min\limits_w \frac{1}{2n}||y-Xw||_2^2+\lambda_n||w||_1$$

have the same indices that are non-zero as the true solution $w^*$? i.e. support($\hat{w}$)=support($w^*$)